# Is this red axel bushing an original Lego part?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Is this an original Lego part? Technic maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is

[Part# x1299 : Technic Bush Old 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x1299&idColor=5#T=C&C=5)

Comment: ahh, early 70s, first time that I saw one of those, thanx!